# Selenium Hub and nodes are not connected when hub machine firewall is enabled

Tags: selenium, grid, windows-firewall

I'm trying to execute automation scripts using selenium grid

But in hub there is no node request is sent when hub machine windows firewall is enabled

Im using hub machine as master & nodes are 2 different machines

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting the appropriate ports or services in the firewall?

Comment: Sorry i'm not clear about your question @Nico, can you please clarify me about this ?

Comment: solution for this issue as earliest is very useful to resolve it. Thanks in advance!